# Add-in for Office 365 Tasks

Tags: office365, add-in, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have already implemented add-ins for Office 365 email and meeting.

Now, I am trying to implement similar add-in for **`Office 365 tasks`**, but I don't get any relevant documents.

Whether Microsoft provides real state for add-in in tasks? If yes, then please suggest some resource which I can refer to add add-in in Office 365 tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add-in is not available for Office 365 tasks.**

We can raise a feature request here

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/